# How to execute multiple lines in Oracle Sql Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sap-ase

I work with Oracle Sql Developer on a Sybase database and struggle with the execution of a simple select statement, which is scattered on multiple lines.

```
    IF 1=1 
    BEGIN
       SELECT 'Foo'
    END
    ELSE
       SELECT 'Bar'
    END
```

If I select these lines in the Query Builder and execute it with `F5` or `CTRL + Enter` I get an `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'` error.

If I write the statement on one line as follow

```
    IF 1=1 BEGIN SELECT 'Foo' END ELSE BEGIN SELECT 'Bar' END
```

I get the expected result.

```
    ---
    Foo
```

Is there an option where I can configure the execution behavior if the statement is scattered on multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - it tells SQL Developer to treat the following string, ended by a / or ; on a line by itself, as a query.

The problem arises from using non-Oracle syntax to run SQL or code blocks...and we're Oracle SQL Developer, not Oracle SQL Developer for Sybase.

The Sybase connectivity is provided for doing database migrations to Oracle, not to do day-to-day database work in ANY type of database other than Oracle Database or TimesTen.

```
/*sqldev:query*/ 
  IF 1=1 
    BEGIN
       SELECT 'Foo'
    END
    ELSE
       SELECT 'Bar'
    END
/
```

Comment: Thanks thatjeffsmith for your hint. Unfortunately I get the `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'` error with this syntax.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @DimaKozhevin i don't have an answer yet as i wasn't sure that would work, and SO doesn't make it easy to post 'try this' or code samples as comments.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: Thanks for adding supplements to your answer. I understand your point of view. But I don't understand why this simple sql statement runs only if I write it on a single line. Is there a way to consult a log file to see what statement is effective send to sybase?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin because we have an oracle statement parser and you'd able to sneak your code through if it's on a single line

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: With other words there is no support for sybase statements which are scattered on multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

The BEGIN and END do not match. Try either dropping the last END or insert a BEGIN after ELSE statement.

```sql
/*sqldev:query*/
  IF 1=1
    BEGIN
       SELECT 'Foo'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       SELECT 'Bar'
    END
```